# How can Remove "Select all" option from material-table actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Is it possible to remove the checkbox for selection all in material-table?
[image]

I don't want to be able to select all the options or at least how I can modify method and display a message?

Here is the sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-resonance-ckx5q?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `showSelectAllCheckbox: false` to **options**